# local variable 'suma' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

1.Pregunta 1
Esta será la forma de evaluar la escritura de código en este curso. Habrá un código incompleto (será una función de Python, pero de eso no debes preocuparte todavía), y tú deberás completarlo.

Por ejemplo, aquí escribe en la línea 3lo siguiente: suma = a + b (cuidando que tenga la misma cantidad de espacios a la izquierda que la línea anterior).

Estas a y b no deberán ser definidas: uno puede pensarlo como que, todos los nombres que van entre paréntesis después del nombre de la función, tendrán el valor correcto.

**Codigo incompleto**

```
def sumador(a, b)

    return suma
```

**Esto es lo que yo hice**

```
def sumador(a, b):

    sumador = suma

    suma = a + b

    return suma
```

**Este es el error**

Incorrecto

> RuntimeErrorElement(RuntimeError,Error on line 2:
> sumador = suma
> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'suma' referenced before assignment
> )

Comment: Y donde has definido `suma`??? En tu código no existe tal variable

Answer (score 0):

la variable suma aún no ha sido asignada, puede ser más simple
podrías regresar los valores sumados:

```
   def sumar(a, b):
       return a + b
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que estás haciendo con este código es definir una función `sumador` que sume el valor de las dos variables que le pasarás (a y b).

Para ello, solo has de efectuar la operación de suma, y asignar el valor a la variable `suma` que es el parámetro que devolverás con `return`.

Tu código está bien, solo sobra la primera línea que escribiste: `sumador = suma`, por lo que que te quedaría como sigue:

```
def sumador(a, b):

suma = a + b

return suma
```

Y para comprobar que funciona, debes usar la función que acabas de definir así:

```
sumador(2,2)
```

esto te devolvería: 4